# Vertically align right DIV based on left DIV height

Tags: html, css

what would be the best way to vertically-align my list items (Reason 1, Reason 2, etc) based on the height of the red DIV (height of the red DIV is driven by the size of the big text on the left) without giving a fixed height to the DIV?. I tried  `display:inline-block` + `vertical-align:middle` but without success http://jsfiddle.net/ggfcN/1/

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="block-left bigtext">Pouquoi<br>faire appel<br> à nos services?</div>
<div class="block-right"><ul class="bullets1-alt">
      <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Reason 1</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Reason 2</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Reason 3</li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bullets1-alt li {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #333;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.bigtext {
    color: #124191;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 53px;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 53px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 980px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;

}

.block-left {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 50%;

}
.block-right {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write:

```
.block-left, .block-right {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:30px 0;
    height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    display:table;
}
```

Remove `float:right` from `.block-right` and `float:left` from `.block-left`

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ggfcN/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works but I would still like to be able to horizontally place the right DIV to the extreme right of the container (wrapper) and left DIV to the extreme left of the container (wrapper). Is there a way to do that? With your solution both DIVs are horizontally aligned to the center of the wrapper. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Not exactly but I think it's worth a new & separate question. You already solved my first issue, many thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline-block but first you need to remove the float

http://jsfiddle.net/ggfcN/4/

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block block-left bigtext">
        Pouquoi<br>faire appel<br> à nos services?
    </div><div class="block block-right"><ul class="bullets1-alt">
          <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Reason 1</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Reason 2</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Reason 3</li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.bullets1-alt li {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #333;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.bigtext {
    color: #124191;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 53px;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 53px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 980px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;

}   

.block {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you still need vendor prefix for some browser when you use box-sizing:

```
.block-left {
    float: left;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 50%;

}
```